# Am I using my noise gate wrong?

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects

So I originally had a Behringer noise gate pedal, didn't think it was working correctly, eventually upgraded to a Boss NS2.

I've put the pedal in the effects loop of my amps (a Bugera TriRec and a Blackstar HT20) and have had the same problem with both pedals. I have to have the threshold dialed up all the way to the left to get any kind of reduction and if I set it to mute mode, I get no sound whatsoever.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you HAVE a noise problem?

Comment: @LaurencePayne yeah - hiss from the amp's gain

Comment: Jamie - ahhh, that is a separate issue...if the amp is introducing hiss, then that is what you need to fix first.

Comment: @DrMayhem that's why I originally put the gate in the FX loop, to try and reduce some of the hiss from the preamp gain. probably need to look into other solutions, but I did try putting the NS-2 before the amp and it helped a noticeable amount!

Comment: If it helps before the amp, then you have a normal situation: noise is from your instrument and cables. This is what a noise gate is for. If your amp is introducing hiss then it is usually a problem - I think I saw you posted on one of the tube amp questions, so you probably are aware of this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place for a noise gate is before the preamp, otherwise you already have that gain stage in place making your signal permanently above the gate threshold (or at least requiring the threshold to be set so high it is effectively pointless)

So run your noise gate first, so you can use the dynamics of the guitar, then the gain stage, with the other effects on the loop, then the output power stage.